# Azure CosmosDB PowerShell Module: (401) not autorised

Tags: powershell, deployment, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the PowerShell Module "CosmosDB" (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CosmosDB) and I repeatedly get (401) not autorized errors when I try to create collections.

I created a context on the account level via

```
New-CosmosDbContext -Account $accountName -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName -MasterKeyType 'PrimaryMasterKey' -BackoffPolicy $backoffPolicy
```

to create a database but using this context seems not to be sufficient to create a collection within the database.

How can I create a collection then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with CosmosDB it is important to know that if you operate on different levels in CosmosDB (account / database / collection / document) a context created on one level (e.g. database) is not autorized to work on another level (e.g. collection). As a result it is necessary to create a context for each level.

For the problem described above it is therefore necessary to create an additional context after the database has been created via

```
New-CosmosDbContext -Account $accountName -Database $databaseName -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName -MasterKeyType 'PrimaryMasterKey' -BackoffPolicy $backoffPolicy
```

This context can then be used to create a collection (see also https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB#working-with-collections)